# How to freeze a block in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Lets say I have hundreds of rows in A B C and I have some calculation in a block from E1 to G11.

Is there a way to freeze that block, so when I scroll down and change something at say row 300 the calculations stick and I can see the result without scrolling back up?

[image: I will not show actual data, but this shows the concept]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this time Google Sheets only is able to freeze rows from top to bottom and columns from left to right, it's not possible to freeze a range in the middle of other columns.

One alternative is that you open two or more windows, one for the range that you want to keep "freezed" while you scroll around in the others.

Comment: I accept this as it confirms that it is not possible.